# Copying files from one server to other server without prompting the password

Tags: ssh, scp

I have two servers namely  ServerA and ServerB , I want to write a script that copy the files form ServerA to ServerB. But when I try to achieve this, it is asking me password while executting the script.

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd '<source Location>'
scp *.csv  SERVERB:<Destination Location>
```

Is there any way to do this without using public keys (because my project not allowing these public keys)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try expect. However using public keys is better solution...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791699/automate-scp-with-multiple-files-with-expect-script

Comment: Thanks for your response Jaroslav ,

I have tried with using expect but it is not working. In my project they are not allow us to use public keys and all.